# How to return letters in a word with newline after going through each word?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to return only the vowels in a word but for the vowels of each word to have their own line.

```
import sys
import re

line = sys.stdin.readline()
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")


while line:
    for word in pattern.findall(line):
        for letter in word:
            if letter in ('aeiouAEIOU'):
                print(letter.lower(), end="")


    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

If the input is a text file:

```
cat
CHO
tree
guess!
bear"
```

I want to return:

```
a
o
ee
ue
ea
```

Right now I am getting:

```
aoeeueea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print a newline at the end of the outer loop:

```
while line:
    for word in pattern.findall(line):
        for letter in word:
            if letter in ('aeiouAEIOU'):
                print(letter.lower(), end="")
        print()
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while line:
    for word in pattern.findall(line):
        print(''.join(letter.lower() for letter in word if letter.lower() in "aeiou"))
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```